# Cypress - loop through an array of elements

Tags: typescript, foreach, click, element, cypress

I have a little piece of code that returns and array of either 1 or 2 web elements (cy.get). The elments are checkboxes, or rather - checkbox labels which works better in this Angular application.

I'm trying to loop through the array and click on each element (checking the checkboxes). If the array contains only one element, it works fine. But when there are two elements, othe second element is clicked twice, resulting in no boxes being selected in the end.

```
if (formal == Formal.KJOP) {
    this.getFinansieringsmuligheterKjop().forEach( (element) => {
        element.click({force:true});
    });
}

private getFinansieringsmuligheterKjop(): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>[] {
    if (Helpers.randomBoolean()) {
        return new Array(formalPage.grunnlanTilKjopLabel);
    } else {
        return new Array(formalPage.grunnlanTilKjopLabel, formalPage.tilskuddUtleieLabel);
    }
}
```

Since it works with regards to the elements being clicked, and also with regards to the number of elements, I'm thinking there's something with the element accessing in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good illustration why the **Page Object** pattern doesn't work very well with Cypress and it's command queue pattern.

The problem is mixing of Cypress queue commands which **run asynchronously** to the test code and the page object code.

Method `getFinansieringsmuligheterKjop()` is not returning an array of elements, it returns and array of `Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>`, which you can think of as an array of unresolved queries.

To solve the problem resolve the elements before returning.

```
private getFinansieringsmuligheterKjop(): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> {

  return formalPage.grunnlanTilKjopLabel.then(label1 => {  // evaluate the first label
    formalPage.tilskuddUtleieLabel.then(label2 => {        // evaluate the second label

      const elements = Helpers.randomBoolean() 
        ? new Array(label1)
        : new Array(label1, label2);

      return elements;
  })
})
```

You must also change the synchronous `.forEach()` for Cypress `.each()` command

```
if (formal == Formal.KJOP) {
  this.getFinansieringsmuligheterKjop().each(label => {
    cy.wrap(label).click();
  });
}
```

---

Comment: Aha. That might explain why I'm having so much trouble converting from Java/Kotlin and Selenium to Cypress! Those responsible for our frontend test code insisted on keeping the PO-model. But what else? What's the alternative? I need some kind of model to build my tests after.

Comment: You can still use a PO if it helps convert test code from a previous framework, but try to keep Cypress commands out of the PO methods and getters. Just return selector strings instead of command results, so above you might use `return cy.get(formalPage.grunnlanTilKjopLabel).then(...` where the `grunnlanTilKjopLabel` property is just a selector string. You will have more flexibility, because in a different test you might want `.find(formalPage.grunnlanTilKjopLabel)` - i.e you can mix and match commands and selectors as required.